# Cannot access commerce order relationship in Add relationship form in Drupal 7 Views

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I have Drupal commerce installed on a Drupal 7 website. I needed to create a view of users and wanted to display the product type they had purchased along with the user name in the View. However I am unable to create a relationship between the view and commerce order even though the module (commerce) has exposed it via hook_views_data

```
'relationship' => array(
  'title' => t('Owner'),
  'help' => t("Relate this order to its owner's user account"),
  'handler' => 'views_handler_relationship',
  'base' => 'users',
  'base field' => 'uid',
  'field' => 'uid',
  'label' => t('Order owner'),
),
```

Can anyone point out what is causing this relationship to not appear in the View add relationship foorm? Is it required to modify any additional configuration settings to bring up this view?

Answer (score 0):

This was a false alarm. I was on a different branch with a single module missing. Enabling the module solved the problem.

Comment: Do you remember which module was missing ?